# Synchronize button action on richfaces

Tags: java, richfaces

I want to execute only once the action linked to a button even if the user click several times on it.

There is my code :

```
public String myMethod() {
    log.info("Call : myMethod");
    if(getLock().tryLock()) {
        try {
            log.info("Lock");
        }
        finally {
            log.info("unlock");
            getLock.unlock();
            return null;
        }
    }
    else {
        log.info("No permission");
        return null;
    }
}
```

My problem :
When I try this, the execution is the following :

- Call : myMethod
- Lock
- Call : myMethod
- No permission
- unlock
- Call : myMethod
- Lock
- unlock

It seems pretty normal but, all my clicks were made before the first action was done.

So my question is does richfaces has a scheduler and start the action when he wants?
Or someone knows a good way to do this correctly?

Thank you reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RichFaces queue to "combined" a number of clicks together and only fire one at the end.